# Python get keyboard input without getting stuck

Tags: python, python-2.7, wallpaper

I'm making a python program that changes my wallpaper every hour, but i want to be able to also change the wallpaper when i press a certain button.

this is the code i've tried

```
while True:
    key = ord(getch())
```

but the only bad part is that it gets stuck on that until i press something. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be able to achieve what you want by using https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pynput.

See also its docs on pythonhosted http://pythonhosted.org/pynput/, especially the section about monitoring the keyboard http://pythonhosted.org/pynput/keyboard.html#monitoring-the-keyboard.

The following is an example from the docs:

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key
from pynput.keyboard import Listener


def on_press(key):
    print('{0} pressed'.format(
        key))

def on_release(key):
    print('{0} release'.format(
        key))
    if key == Key.esc:
        # Stop listener
        return False

# Collect events until released
with Listener(
        on_press=on_press,
        on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

It will print every key you press until you press *ESC*, after which it will terminate.

Note that there are some operating system specific things to consider, for example on *OSX* the process must run as root.

Answer (score 1):

I somehow accidentally found this.

```
    import msvcrt

    if msvcrt.kbhit():
        Key = ord(getch())
        if Key ==96:
            #Do something here
```

And that seems to work. I think msvcrt.kbhit() is waiting for an keypress. Key = ord(getch()) takes the keypress and if Key ==96: checks if its the right keypress